# How to use a webcam that is not officially for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, webcam

I was just wondering if I could use a normal webcam that is NOT officialy Raspberry Pi endorsed?

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use a standard USB webcam with the Pi.

For example if you are running Raspbian:

First install `fswebcam`:

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

You can use the webcam by running:

```
fswebcam image.jpg
```

This will take a jpeg picture and save it with the filename image.

Use the `-r` tag to specify the resolution of the image:

```
fswebcam -r 1280x720 image2.jpg
```

For more information on this you can check out the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/).

Quick side note:

There isn't any officially endorsed by the Raspberry Pi Foundation webcams as far as I am aware. Although you might be interested in the  Raspberry Pi Camera module which connects via a ribbon cable to the camera connector on the Pi. This is a product that was released by the Foundation.